# C - What does this line mean?

Tags: c, coding-style, embedded

I am trying to understand what the following line of the worst-ever-seen C code (from [uboot](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/WebHome) project) mean:

```
rc = ((ulong (*)(bd_t *, int, char *[]))addr) (bd, --argc, &argv[1]);
```

What is it? A function call? 
Can it be more readable?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you tell us the declared type of the different variables present in this line?

Comment: Can it be more readable?

Hell no! Obfuscate it!

Comment: @David: I am sorry, but I have no idea. I have just opened this project and am trying to understand what is what.

Comment: This is Bad Programmerese for "run screaming."

Comment: I am impressed. That's one hell of C-fu.

Comment: @Adam: yes but you have to admit that it is astonishing beautiful in its intrinsic horror.

Comment: Stefano, I will admit that it has a certain Lovecraftian quality to it.

Comment: Why don't you just ask `cdecl`?

Comment: Mmmm casting to function pointer dessert with --argc cherry on the top :o) It's actually readable, just mental parsing can take a while. Btw correct project address is: http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/WebHome

Comment: @MaR: thanks for updated address

Comment: You should read the comment that's just above that line.  It says...  wait!  There's no comment!  FAIL!

Comment: now I remember why I hate 'C'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, it's a function call.

It casts the value in `addr` to a function pointer which accepts `(bd_t *, int, char *[])` as arguments and returns a `ulong`, and calls the function. It could be sugared into:

```
typedef ulong (*bd_function)(bd_t *bd, int argc, char *argv[]);

bd_function bdfunc = (bd_function) addr;

rc = bdfunc(bd, --argc, &argv[1]);
```

This might be overkill, to introduce a `typedef` if this only happens once, but I feel it helps a lot to be able to look at the function pointer's type separately.

Comment: Since the typedef makes the thing readable, it isn't overkill.

Comment: It isn't overkill in the same way that anitbiotics aren't an overreaction to infection.

Answer (score 12):

It casts `addr` to a function pointer which accepts `(bd_t *, int, char *[])` as arguments and returns a `long`, then invokes it with the arguments `(bd, --argc, &argv[1])`.

Comment: Right. And to answer the second question, no, it can not be made more readable.

Comment: @Jason: Sure it can (and should), see unwind's answer.

Comment: Finnegan's Wake is also perfectly readable, but extracting meaning from it is substantially difficult.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That just moves the perceived unreadability elsewhere. (To be clear, I'm not agreeing that either version is unreadable. Just that if someone were to find the original unreadable, offloading part of the unreadability elsewhere doesn't reduce the unreadability.)

Comment: @Stephen: Plenty of C programmers, particularly newer ones, don't have to deal with function pointers often at all. Moreover, it's much better programming practice to declare the pointer type (if you're going to have to use one) in the same header where you declare the function, so that if you need to change the function, you don't break every individual hand-coded cast. Maintenance 101, in my view.

Comment: I don't see using a typedef as improving readability, but if the function pointer type is used in multiple places then it makes sense to use one to remove the duplication.

However, if the function pointer type is a one-off then I don't see a problem with using it inline.

My two cents.

Comment: @Jason: I disagree, for the reasons in my comment to Stephen. But it's all good, smart people can disagree with each other. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I completely agree with your maintenance comments; that is a very good reason to provide such a `typedef`. I will agree that we can agreeably disagree on whether or not it improves the readability to someone that doesn't find the original version readable. :-)

Comment: Offloading *hard part* to typedef helps in scenarios where you read code, but do not want to inspect in detail this particular bit. With typedef it looks like ordinary function call and you can "parse" it quicker. In contrast this can be disadvatge when you are looking for strange errors if - for example - your function pointer is not set right. Good naming is essential when doing typedef (like fp_<name> or something) so you can detect function pointers if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your question, but might be of interest:

- [Reading C Declarations](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/reading-c-declarations.html)
- [How To Read C Declarations](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations)

> Start at the variable name (or
>   innermost construct if no identifier
>   is present. Look right without jumping
>   over a right parenthesis; say what you
>   see. Look left again without jumping
>   over a parenthesis; say what you see.
>   Jump out a level of parentheses if
>   any. Look right; say what you see.
>   Look left; say what you see. Continue
>   in this manner until you say the
>   variable type or return type.

Answer (score 2):

`ulong (*)(bd_t *, int, char *[])` is the type of a function that takes a pointer to a `bd_t`, an `int`, and a pointer to a `char` array, and returns a `ulong`.

The code is casting `addr` to such a function, and then calling it with `bd`, `--argc`, and `&argv[1]` as parameters, and assigning the result to `rc`.

Answer (score 2):

addr must be the location in memory to a function that looks like

```
ulong *funcname(bd_t*, int, char*[])
```

and it's being called with the paramerers like

```
rc = funcname(bd, --argc, &argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're typecasting "addr" to a pointer to a function returning a ulong that takes a bd_t *, an int and a char *[] as parameters, and then calling the function with the parameters bd, --argc, &argv [1].